# Mapping string into integers

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Suppose I have the following list,

```
l = {{"b", "c", "d"}, {"e", "b"}, {"a", "b", "d", "e"}}
```

and further suppose I have the following association,

```
l1=<|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d", 5 -> "e"|>
```

I wonder how can I replace the keys into my list such that I get,

```
{{2, 3, 4}, {5, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following gives you a "reversed" version of your association, with keys and values flipped:

```
l1 = <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d", 5 -> "e"|>;

lookup = First /@ PositionIndex@l1
(* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5|> *)
```

You can then use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) to do the replacement:

```
l = {{"b", "c", "d"}, {"e", "b"}, {"a", "b", "d", "e"}};

l /. lookup
(* {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5}} *)
```

#### Alternatives

Other possible solutions for creating `lookup`:

```
lookup = <|Reverse /@ Normal@l1|>
lookup = Reverse /@ Normal@l1 (* doesn't need to be an association *)
```

Answer (score 10):

For the specific numbering in OP, you can also use [`LetterNumber`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LetterNumber.html):

```
LetterNumber[l]
```

> {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5}}

Answer (score 7):

```
l /. Reverse /@ Normal[l1]

(* {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5}} *)
```

or

```
l /. AssociationMap[Reverse, l1]

(* {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular mapping, you could also use [`ToCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode):

```
ToCharacterCode[StringJoin /@ l] - First@ToCharacterCode@"a" + 1
```

> {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5}}